# Method to free/reset RAM in Python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, ipython, ram

I am struggling to find a way to actually free the RAM in Python.
By monitoring its usage with a `htop` I try to free the RAM space but the usual `del` or `gc.collect()` do not work.
This was in a context of very complex code (functions, libraries, methods...).

So, I decided to write down a very simple script and test it while monitoring on htop:

```py
import numpy as np
import gc

y = []
for i in range(10000):
   y.append( np.zeros( 1000 )  )

del y
g.collect()
%reset -f
```

Even after a `%reset -f` the RAM is not freed.
The only way to free it is to perform an `exit` in the ipython console.

Is there a command to actually free the RAM?

Comment: Giving memory back to the OS is not always trivial or possible. There are many questions about this but often no conclusive answer. At least know that the memory will be reused before Python asks for new memory.